Differentiate inside path integral
I am learning about QFT and I was wondering if it makes sense to differentiate the partition function/ path integral with respect to one of the parameters in the Lagrangian (either renormalized or not) in order to obtain integrated identities for $n$-point functions. For example, suppose that i know the partition function, is the following identity true?
$$-\partial_{m^2} \left[ \int \mathcal{D}\phi \, e^{-\int d^Dx \, \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \phi(x))^2 +\frac{m^2}{2} \phi^2(x)} \right] = \int \mathcal{D}\phi \int d^D y \, \frac{\phi^2 (y)}{2} e^{-\int d^D x \, \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \phi(x))^2 +\frac{m^2}{2} \phi^2(x)} = \frac{1}{2} \int d^D y \, \langle \phi^2 (y) \rangle$$
where $\langle ... \rangle$ is not normalized by the vacuum partition function. I am doing an example in free theory for simplicity, I know that my example is trivial. My question is if this strategy is correct and if so, if it is always valid (even non-perturbatively)?

The problem with your result is that it is badly divergent as-is. Why not use a zeta regularization of the partition function, expressing it as $e^{-\zeta_{\square-m^2}'(0)}$, and then differentiating on $m^2$?

That has been already explored years ago: The exact renormalization group equation is usually derived via differentiating the  partition function/ functional integral with some cut off scale $\Lambda$. But one can arrive at similar renormalization group equation by differentiating the  partition function/ functional integral with either mass $m$ or coupling constant $\lambda$.

When testing conjectured perturbative formulae (e.g. identities associated with perturbations from Gaussian theories), sometimes it is easier conceptually to work in terms of (finite) multivariable functions such as vector models.  These models don't require fancy mathematics (just multivariable calculus), and you can derive results that are essentially equivalent to those of perturbative QFT.  Generally in QFT if you want to prove a result nonperturbatively, you need to first regularize the result and show that it holds in the continuum (usually asymptotic) limit: this could either involve results that hold exactly for all values of a regularizer, or (more typically) results that hold modulo a small error term that vanishes in the continuum/asymptotic limit.  Your result for example applies to Gaussian free fields because it applies exactly to any approximate Gaussian free field (e.g. if you restrict the 'field measure' to any finite subspace, e.g. in Fourier space, the result will apply; although restricting to a subspace breaks Lorentz invariance, you regain Poincaré symmetry in the "continuum limit" as you add a complete set of plane wave basis functions.)
